# PyMongo Aggregation create pipline from string

Tags: python, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am looking for a possibility to store the aggregation command e.g. in a text file to load that by python/pymongo and execute that.

Currently, I find a lot of examples using the pipe line in pymongo. But how do I to handle that when I want to outsource the aggregation command in a text file outside my pymongo code.

Hope you know what I mean :-).

Thx in advance for your help!

tom

Comment: Hi tommired. welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please provide some code that you have tried?

Comment: Hey great idea.  Typically SO answerers wants something a little more hands on to deal with.  You could post your script and your pipeline and we could take a stab at it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could store your pipeline data in a text file:

pipe.txt

```
[
  {"$match": 
    {"year":1984}
  }
]
```

You could then use Python's JSON package and `loads` method to interpret the data in your file.  You can then use this for aggregating:

```
import pymongo, json
client=pymongo.MongoClient('your connection, credentials here')
db=client.yourDatabase
with open('pipe.txt','r') as f:
    pipeline = json.loads(f.read())

data=db.yourCollection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Hey EoinS, thanks for your answer. I will try it immediately. Looks very good.
You wrote it's not the best way to do that in this way. What you mean with storing the pipeline elements in a text and build a list/dict ? Do you have an example?

Comment: @tommired I just updated the answer to use json.loads instead of eval.  This is good practice and there are no issues with this approach!

Comment: Hi EoinS, it's working perfectly. But when I try to use a date in the string I get a empty result. Do you know how I have to write the date format when I use the json.loads method?

Example:

{ "BroadcastDay" : "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000+0000"} ==> no resultset

{ "test" : 1} ==> it works

Comment: @tommired I would ask another question and post what you have so far with some sample data.  I think you'll find the SO community very helpful!